# Changing zoom level steps of Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, zoom

When I zoom with my Macbook's trackpad by pinch gesture, elements get blurry because of decimal zoom level like "169,11%".

[image: Zoom level]

Is there a way to change zoom steps to use only integers?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about adjusting the intervals.  Since the motion of your fingers on the zoom is a fluid one, I doubt it.

Personally, I use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> instead.

Alternatively, you can open your `Navigator` (Window > Navigator) and use that.  I always have mine placed at the top of my right-hand tool bar, for easier navigation, and you can click on the little/big mountains to zoom out/in.

[image]

Comment: Pinching and dragging with trackpad is way easier, but thank you I will use keyboard shortcut that you mentioned untill someone shows a way for what I requested.

Comment: @xecute If you're using a mouse, you can also hold down OPTION and scroll up/down with the mouse using the mousewheel or Mac equivalent; though this will give you the same effect as pinching.

Comment: @xecute - "I would rather not use the tools I've been given that do exactly what I want" is not a great reaction. Cmd+1 will give you 100%. Cmd + + and Cmd + - will give you convenient integer fractions from there.

Comment: @StanRogers what the hack? How could you compare pinching with CMD-"+"?

Comment: @JohnManly as I said, pinching trackpad is very useful and easy, but thank you.

Comment: @StanRogersGlad my sentiments exactly.

Comment: @xecute Yes however its not useful because it does not fulfill your need. So your arguing it would be usefull if you could control it better. Ergo your arguing its not useful as it is. You can not argue both ways.